# Slow Adagrad Convergence

Tags: python, machine-learning, gradient-descent

I'm working on a comparison of popular gradient descent algorithms in Python. [Here](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/CalebEverett/gd_algorithms/blob/master/gd_algorithms.ipynb) is a link to the notebook I've got going.

The Adagrad algorithm converges at a much slower rate than the plain vanilla batch, stochastic and mini-batch algorithms. I was expecting it to be an improvement from the basic methods. Is the difference attributable to one or more of the factors below or something else, or is this the expected result?

1. The test data set is small and Adagrad performs relatively better on larger data sets
2. Something having to do with the characteristics of the sample data
3. Something having to do with the parameters
4. An error in the code

Here is the code for Adagrad - it is also the last one in the [notebook](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/CalebEverett/gd_algorithms/blob/master/gd_algorithms.ipynb).

```
def gd_adagrad(data, alpha, num_iter, b=1):
    m, N = data.shape
    Xy = np.ones((m,N+1))
    Xy[:,1:] = data
    theta = np.ones(N)
    grad_hist = 0
    for i in range(num_iter):
        np.random.shuffle(Xy)
        batches = np.split(Xy, np.arange(b, m, b))
        for B_x, B_y in ((B[:,:-1],B[:,-1]) for B in batches):
            loss_B = B_x.dot(theta) - B_y
            gradient = B_x.T.dot(loss_B) / B_x.shape[0]
            grad_hist += np.square(gradient)
            theta = theta - alpha * gradient / (10**-6 + np.sqrt(grad_hist))
    return theta

theta = gd_adagrad(data_norm, alpha*10, 150, 50)
```

Comment: what do you mean by "than the plain vanilla batch, stochastic and mini-batch algorithms" - what are you comparing adagrad to? Adagrad is **not** alternative to batching, it is alternative to doing pure gradient-based update, nothing more.

Comment: I was thinking of it as an alternative approach to solving a problem, meaning that I apply each method in total to a particular data set to determine the difference in their performance (in the [notebook](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/CalebEverett/gd_algorithms/blob/master/gd_algorithms.ipynb)). But having thought about this a bit more, I think this is the expected result since Adagrad, by definition, reduces the learning rate.

Comment: Here is a [notebook](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/CalebEverett/pysgd/blob/master/pysgd.ipynb) with working versions of the basic algorithms.

Comment: Have you looked at [lightning](https://github.com/mblondel/lightning) ? Cython, tuned for sparse problems -- no minibatch. His Adagrad is quite different from Dyer Adagrad, faster and better on mnist49 and ijcnn.